# Rails:create association between an element and a 2nd level nested element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested

The following system is for managing contacts.
Each contact belongs to an organisation, and each organisation has many locations. A contact is also related to one location from the parent organisation.
The organisation model looks like this

```
has_many :contacts
has_many :locations
accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a["name"].blank? }
```

I want it to accept nested attributes for locations because when a user adds an organisation he can also add a location for it on the fly.

The contact model looks like this

```
  has_one :location
  belongs_to  :organisation
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :organisation
```

Same story, when a contact is added I want the user to be able to add the organisation on the fly, but the organisation needs to have a location, so a second level of nesting exists in the view to also create the location for the organsiation.
It works fine, it adds the contact, it adds the organisation and the location, it creates the association between the location and the organisation but what happens is that I have a field "location_id" in contact and I want to have in that the id of the location added for the organisation on the fly. Does anyone know a clean way to do it through the model or do I have to workaround it with some tweaks in the controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `@location = @contact.build_location` it should create the ID that you are currently missing, even though the id of @contact does not exist at the time of the build.